# Como rodar comandos no plugin do Maven para Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Uso o plugin do Maven para Eclipse mas não domino muito a tecnologia.

Tem como rodar comandos do Maven (digitando mesmo: `mvn compile` por exemplo) sem ter que instalar o Maven à parte?

As respostas que encontrei na Internet não atendem essa questão.

Como faria isso?

Obs.: Eclipse JEE. Versão: 2019-09 R (4.13.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri.

1) Clique com o botão direito no `pom.xml`

2) Selecione `Run As > Run Configurations...`

3) Abrirá uma janela `Create, manage and run configurations`.

4) Do lado esquerdo abaixo de `Maven Build` está a lista de configurações (comandos) já executados. Você pode apagar ou adicionar comandos nessa lista (é uma interface meio desajeitada mesmo, paciência). Do lado direito você define qual comando deseja rodar (`goal`), por exemplo: `compile`. E clica no botão `Run` para executar.